# forEach loop using !variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this func. In the beginning I have this variable - canBeDeleted. It is an array; Got commets from my teacher it is better keep using this variable, not to create another one(canNotBeDeleted) because they are pretty similar; So I am trying to rewrite it converting it into a boolean (!canBedeleted). But I have troubles with it.

What is the best way to do it?

```
filterItems = () => {
  const { options, canBeDeleted } = this.props;
  const canNotBeDeleted = options.filter(item => !canBeDeleted.includes(item.id));
  options.forEach((gItem) => {
    const opt = gItem;
    canNotBeDeleted.forEach((item) => {
      opt.id === item.id && (opt.canNotBeDeleted = true);
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can omit `options.forEach` and only use `canNotBeDeleted.forEach` like below. As your are already filtering your `options` and `canNotBeDeleted` is array which needs to set `canNotBeDeleted = true;`

```
filterItems = () => {
  const { options, canBeDeleted } = this.props;
  const canNotBeDeleted = options.filter(item => !canBeDeleted.includes(item.id));
  canNotBeDeleted.forEach((gItem) => {
    gItem.canNotBeDeleted = true;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use one single for loop.

**Like this**

```js
filterItems = () => {
  const { options, canBeDeleted } = this.props;
  for(let i=0; i< options.length; i++){
    if(!canBeDeleted.includes(options[i].id)){
      options[i].canNotBeDeleted = true;//mutate the array
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: hi - is it working? any questions please let me know.